# Angular Material "Form-Field" with appearance="outline" is cut off from other labels

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-form-field

After updating to Angular Material v15 our form fields look like this (sometimes - depending on if there is a margin/padding from the element above):

[image: cut off label]

This is how it looked like before:

[image: not cut off]

From what I can see (and what they also write in the documentation) they changed the margins. Compare (new version):

[image: margins]

vs previous version:

[image: v14 (not cut off)]

Also to proof that it's not only in our application I prepared a stackblitz sample that shows this behavior as well, see: [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/1p4tur-jh9rln?file=src%2Fexample%2Fform-field-appearance-example.html)

**I have fixed the label being "cut off" by adding a `padding-top: 8px` to all `mat-form-field`s. However, this feels like a workaround.
Is there any better solution for this?**

Comment: Happens in my angular app after upgrading angular to v14 (from v9). Looks like they added some box-sizing stuff but I didn't manage to fix it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I got a better solution, in my case I am working with a `<mat-grid-tile>` and to resolve the issue I've just setted `overflow: visible` on the mat-grid-tile.
I'm getting an error trying to build the Stackblitz example that you shared but I guess that in your case you should add the `overflow` property on the `<mat-form-field>` container ; )

[image: Solution proof image]